# MySQL parse error in nodejs but works from cmd

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
START TRANSACTION; 

INSERT INTO cards SET `Name` = 'aaa'; 

COMMIT;
```

Smallest example of code that does not work when called from nodejs
it works from command line.

How to fix it without removing transactions?

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't work about it? What is it meant to do, and what does it actually do?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention...
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO cards (Name)

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are another queries, so it must be enabled in connection

```
var connection =  mysql.createConnection( { multipleStatements: true }
```

after this edit whole thing works like a charm.

Comment: Don't do that.  Execute them separately.  Enabling multiple statements opens up numerous security vulnerabilities.  https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Can't find any other than SQL injection - but only if you don't escape properly.

Am I missing something?